# How to fix ussd codes in samsung

Tags: android

to all forum members

I'm new here, hope you welcome to me here
ok so whats mine problem ? i have converted rom , like samsung sprint to international, everything is working fine, but just one problem is there
USSD codes ! ok in ussd codes this codes working fine *#06# *#1234# 
but the when i try to active any kind of sim pakage like this *112# or *111# etc so its gone to make call ,

So how can I fix this issue

Is there any person who,s explain me with l little details ?

Thanks to all

Comment: String ussdCode = "*" + "123" + Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));

Comment: try this # symbol has to encode like above

Answer (score 0):

Without encode # symbol it goes to call leaving with #symbol

Try below code

```
  String ussdCode = "*" + "111" + Uri.encode("#");
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
```

need below permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: thanks brother for too quick reply. but sorry i can,t get it

Comment: acutely i beginner in development , and i make this roms but now i,m very confused how can i fix this issue?

Comment: how and where i add this permissions? in bulid prop?

Comment: try above code .dont add # symbol with usse number .after number encode #.means if you ussd code is *111*# then  String ussdCode = "*" + "111" + Uri.encode("#");

Comment: Permission you have to add in manifest file above application tag

Comment: most important thing i,m window user

Comment: Try once add permission in manifest and  just copy past that code in button click.

Comment: no no please i,m not clear , i,m sorry for disturb to all of you

Comment: where i add this permissions ?

Comment: and brother can you please give me your any kind of contact?